# Gmail API and PubSub: Hit external webhook with custom header?

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, supabase

I want to trigger a Supabase function whenever a new email arrives in Gmail.

If I understand [Google's Instructions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) correctly, this needs to be done using Google's Pub/Sub service.

However, Supabase requires an authorization header to be sent with the POST request to the webhook, and while Pub/Sub allows for authorization, it only seems to support service accounts, and not just setting a simple `Bearer` token.

It seems like either polling or setting up a proxy webhook would be the only feasible options left—unless I'm missing a simpler way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy the function to not require the auth headers by adding the `--no-verify-jwt` flag when deploying your functions.

From the [edge functions docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions/quickstart#deploy-to-production)

> By default, Edge Functions require a valid JWT in the authorization header. This header is automatically set when invoking your function via a Supabase client library.
> If you want to use Edge Functions to handle webhooks (e.g. Stripe payment webhooks etc.), you need to pass the --no-verify-jwt flag when deploying your function.

Comment: Perfect, somehow missed that :-) Thanks!